# Check condition before method call

Tags: python

I have a class named Server which can be started and stopped. Certain methods should not be called unless the Server is started, in which case a NotConnectedException should be raised. Is there a way to call a method before every method in a class and determine if class variable _started is set to True?

I tried using a decorator, but the decorator function does not have access to the class variable. I was trying to do something like this:

```
class Server(object):
    _started = False
    def started(self):
        if(self._started == False):
            raise NotConnectedException

    @started
    def doServerAction(self):
       ...
```

Comment: did you try putting the decorator directly in the class? I haven't worked enough on decorators to know how well this would work, but it's where I would start looking

Comment: as this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366713/can-a-python-decorator-of-an-instance-method-access-the-class) said, if it's python2.6 or later, there is a way for your decorator to access the class variable

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes, the decorator is in the class.

Comment: @xvatar It looks like that might be close, but I'm still not sure how I would access the class variable in the method decorator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember what decorators *are*:

```
@decorate
def foo(...):
    ...
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
def foo(...):
    ...
foo = decorate(foo)
```

The decorator is called on the *function*, so calling the first parameter *self* makes no sense. Also, the decorator is called on the function when it is defined, and whatever it returns is used in place of the function. So even if your `started` decorator didn't throw an `AttributeError` by trying to access the `_started` attribute of a function, it would then return `None`, making all your methods set to `None`, and thus not even be callable.

What you want is something like this:

```
import functools

def started(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._started:
            raise ...
        else:
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Almost all decorators are of this form; they take a function, create a wrapper that does something "around" the received function, and then return the wrapper. The use of `functools.wraps` here is a convenience if you ever end up working with this code in an interactive interpreter session; it automatically updates the `wrapper` function with the name and docstring of the original function, which makes the decorated functions "look like" the original function a bit more.

It's irrelevant whether this is defined inside the class or not.