# Python mock library not returning correct mock object for 'patch'

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the mock library to return a specific mock object with patch. No matter what I try, if I instantiate a new object inside my 'with' clause, I get a generic Mock object, not my customised one.

Here's my code using logging as an example:

```
    import logging

    my_mock = Mock()
    my_mock.id = 'i-12341234'

    with patch('logging.PlaceHolder', new=my_mock) as mockobj:
        print mockobj.id          # correctly prints 'i-12341234'

        newobj = logging.PlaceHolder(None)
        print newobj.id           # prints <Mock name='mock().id' id='47607184'>
```

How can I get mock to return my_mock every time a new instance of logging.Placeholder is instantiated?

As it turns out subclassing Mock and passing it using new_callable works. Since I've spent the time trying to get the version above working I'd still appreciate and answer.

Comment: Have you looked at [this maybe-related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980962/mocking-a-classs-construction)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import logging
from mock import Mock, patch

my_mock = Mock()
my_mock.id = 'i-12341234'

with patch('logging.PlaceHolder', new=my_mock) as mockobj:
    mockobj.return_value = mockobj # <-- added this line.
    print mockobj.id
    newobj = logging.PlaceHolder(None)
    print newobj.id
```

**Alternative**

```
import logging
from mock import Mock, patch

my_mock = Mock()
my_mock.id = 'i-12341234'
my_mock.return_value = my_mock # <---

with patch('logging.PlaceHolder', new=my_mock) as mockobj:
    assert mockobj.id == 'i-12341234'
    newobj = logging.PlaceHolder(None)
    assert newobj.id == 'i-12341234'
```

Comment: how is this different to my code (apart from importing Mock & patch?)

Comment: @user1491250, You code patch `loggin.PlaceHolder`, but does not patch `logging.PlaceHolder()`.

Comment: That *definitely* needs adding to the documentation :-) Thanks