# Does python consider any method without cls or self arguments implicitly as static?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following are test classes with methods not taking in cls or self arguments and dont have @staticmethod decorator. They work like normal static methods without complaining about arguments. This seems contrary to my understanding of python methods. Does python automatically treat non-class, non-instance methods as static?

```
>>> class Test():
... def testme(s):
...  print(s)
...
>>> Test.testme('hello')
hello

>>> class Test():
...  def testme():
...   print('no')
...
>>> Test.testme()
no
```

P.S: I am using python3.4

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this doesn't work in Python 2:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def testme():
...         print 'no'
...
>>> Test.testme()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-74-09d78063da08>", line 1, in <module>
    Test.testme()
TypeError: unbound method testme() must be called with Test instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

But in Python 3, unbound methods were removed, as Alex Martelli points out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589311/get-defining-class-of-unbound-method-object-in-python-3/3589335#3589335). So really all you're doing is calling a plain function that happens to be defined inside the Test class.

Answer (score 3):

It *sort of* does, yes. However, note that if you call such an *"implicit static method"* on an *instance*, you will get an error:

```
>>> Test().testme()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    Test().testme()
TypeError: testme() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

This is because the `self` parameter **still gets passed**, which doesn't happen with a proper `@staticmethod`:

```
>>> class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def testme():
        print('no')


>>> Test.testme()
no
>>> Test().testme()
no
```

Comment: While only indirectly relevant to the question and answer here, there's an interesting [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1669524/660848) on how `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod` behave.