# Alternatives to decorators for saving metadata about classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I'm writing a GUI library, and I'd like to let the programmer provide meta-information about their program which I can use to fine-tune the GUI. I was planning to use function decorators for this purpose, for example like this:

```
class App:
    @Useraction(description='close the program', hotkey='ctrl+q')
    def quit(self):
        sys.exit()
```

The problem is that this information needs to be bound to the respective class. For example, if the program is an image editor, it might have an `Image` class which provides some more Useractions:

```
class Image:
    @Useraction(description='invert the colors')
    def invert_colors(self):
        ...
```

However, since the concept of unbound methods has been removed in python 3, there doesn't seem to be a way to find a function's defining class. (I found [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25959545/1222951), but that doesn't work in a decorator.)

So, since it looks like decorators aren't going to work, what would be the best way to do this? I'd like to avoid having code like

```
class App:
    def quit(self):
        sys.exit()

Useraction(App.quit, description='close the program', hotkey='ctrl+q')
```

if at all possible.

---

For completeness' sake, the `@Useraction` decorator would look somewhat like this:

```
class_metadata= defaultdict(dict)
def Useraction(**meta):
    def wrap(f):
        cls= get_defining_class(f)
        class_metadata[cls][f]= meta
        return f
    return wrap
```

Comment: You could use in addition a class decorator or metaclass to inspect the methods and save their metadata on the class.

Comment: `getattr(inspect.getmodule(f), f.__qualname__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])` might be hacky, but saves you the trouble of writing a metaclass. The string `f.__qualname__.rsplit('.', 1)[0]` might already suffice as a key for your `defaultdict`

Comment: `f.__qualname__.split('.')[0]` works though and gives you the class name which might be enough as a dict key.

Comment: @schwobaseggl That could work. It doesn't feel good to code it that way, but I guess it wouldn't cause problems in most real-world scenarios and it's a lot easier/nicer to use than a metaclass.

Comment: I just realized that if I only use the name of the class, it'll cause problems with inheritance. Classes wouldn't inherit any metadata from their parents. Maybe a metaclass is the way to go after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using decorators to add meta data to methods. That is fine. It can be done e.g. this way:

```
def user_action(description):
    def decorate(func):
        func.user_action = {'description': description}
        return func
    return decorate
```

Now, you want to collect that data and store it in a global dictionary in form `class_metadata[cls][f]= meta`. For that, you need to find all decorated methods and their classes.

The simplest way to do that is probably using metaclasses. In metaclass, you can define what happens when a class is created. In this case, go through all methods of the class, find decorated methods and store them in the dictionary:

```
class UserActionMeta(type):
    user_action_meta_data = collections.defaultdict(dict)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        rtn = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        for attr in attrs.values():
            if hasattr(attr, 'user_action'):
                UserActionMeta.user_action_meta_data[rtn][attr] = attr.user_action
        return rtn
```

*I have put the global dictionary `user_action_meta_data` in the meta class just because it felt logical. It can be anywhere.*

Now, just use that in any class:

```
class X(metaclass=UserActionMeta):

    @user_action('Exit the application')
    def exit(self):
        pass
```

Static `UserActionMeta.user_action_meta_data` now contains the data you want:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {<class '__main__.X'>: {<function exit at 0x00000000029F36C8>: {'description': 'Exit the application'}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to make decorators work with the `inspect` module, but it's not a great solution, so I'm still open to better suggestions.

Basically what I'm doing is to traverse the interpreter stack until I find the current class. Since no class object exists at this time, I extract the class's qualname and module instead.

```
import inspect

def get_current_class():
    """
    Returns the name of the current module and the name of the class that is currently being created.
    Has to be called in class-level code, for example:

    def deco(f):
        print(get_current_class())
        return f

    def deco2(arg):
        def wrap(f):
            print(get_current_class())
            return f
        return wrap

    class Foo:
        print(get_current_class())

        @deco
        def f(self):
            pass

        @deco2('foobar')
        def f2(self):
            pass
    """
    frame= inspect.currentframe()
    while True:
        frame= frame.f_back
        if '__module__' in frame.f_locals:
            break
    dict_= frame.f_locals
    cls= (dict_['__module__'], dict_['__qualname__'])
    return cls
```

Then in a sort of post-processing step, I use the module and class names to find the actual class object.

```
def postprocess():
    global class_metadata

    def findclass(module, qualname):
        scope= sys.modules[module]
        for name in qualname.split('.'):
            scope= getattr(scope, name)
        return scope

    class_metadata= {findclass(cls[0], cls[1]):meta for cls,meta in class_metadata.items()}
```

The problem with this solution is the delayed class lookup. If classes are overwritten or deleted, the post-processing step will find the wrong class or fail altogether. Example:

```
class C:
    @Useraction(hotkey='ctrl+f')
    def f(self):
        print('f')

class C:
    pass

postprocess()
```