# Why can instance methods be called as class methods in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Consider the following class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        print(self)
```

**In Python 2** (2.7.13), calling `bar()` as a class method raises an exception:

```
>>> Foo.bar('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

>>> Foo.bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

When `bar()` is called as an instance method it recognizes `self` as the instance when called without arguments

```
>>> Foo().bar('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bar() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

>>> Foo().bar()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x10a8e1a10>
```

**In Python 3** (3.6.0), when calling `bar()` as a class method, the first argument is accepted as `self`:

```
>>> Foo.bar('hello')
hello

>>> Foo.bar()
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Calling `bar()` as an instance method works as in Python 2

```
>>> Foo().bar('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bar() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

>>> Foo().bar()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x104ab34a8>
```

Comment: Good question. seems that they removed the check python 3. Why? maybe because "better ask for forgiveness than permission". If it works, good for you, else, you'll get an exception at some point afterwards.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that a suitably skilled and determined dupe hunter could find a dupe of this question because I'm pretty sure that I've seen it before...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589311/get-defining-class-of-unbound-method-object-in-python-3 but I wouldn't call that a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Python 3, `Foo.bar` is just that `bar` function you wrote. It takes one parameter, which happens to be named `self`, and prints it. You can call that function on anything, and it will print whatever argument you pass it.

On Python 2, `Foo.bar` isn't quite the `bar` function you wrote. When you access `Foo.bar`, Python generates an *unbound method object* wrapping the `bar` function. The unbound method object works mostly like the `bar` function, with the main difference of validating that its first argument is an instance of `Foo`. You could do

```
Foo.bar(some_foo_instance)
```

which would work like `some_foo_instance.bar()`, but calling `Foo`'s implementation, bypassing any overrides in subclasses. You couldn't do `Foo.bar('hello')`, though.

[Python 3 removed unbound method objects.](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods) They don't exist any more. That makes the language a bit simpler, but it removes the validation unbound method objects used to perform.