# Get list of callables defined in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, metaprogramming

If I have a class, how can I get a list of functions, methods and other callables defined in this class (so nothing inherited from object, etc.)?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589311/get-defining-class-of-unbound-method-object-in-python-3/25959545#25959545), but it requires me to first get a complete list of attributes and then call this method for each callable and compare classes.

Is there a more simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

The special attribute `__dict__` contains all members attributes defined in a class. It may not exists for objects where the class defined a `__slots__` attribute, but I have never seen a metaclass (the class of class objects) defining it.

You can then use `inspect.isfunction` to know where an attribute is callable.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the above answer, you can either use `dir(yourClass)` or you can use use `help(yourClass)`.

Comment: It would return all callables, not only those defined in the class itself