# How do I make sure a super method is called on child classes method on Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

How to make it sure in a parent class method that `super` is called in its children methods which override the parent method? I found this question in SO for other languages except for Python.

Comment: `super().func()`?

Comment: I mean making sure in the Parent class that its children will call super().func() when overriding the method

Comment: Maybe that's not possible at all in Python, but I was imaging something similar to `@abstractmethod`, or any other mechanism

Comment: You can't do it, you can't enforce implementation of functions in a derived class from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to enforce that a child class method must call the parent class method when it overrides it.

Nevertheless, a workaround could be to use a decorator calling the overriden method.

Based on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25959545/3903832),

```
import inspect 


def get_class_that_defined_method(meth):
    if inspect.ismethod(meth):
        for cls in inspect.getmro(meth.__self__.__class__):
            if meth.__name__ in cls.__dict__:
                return cls
    if inspect.isfunction(meth):
        return getattr(inspect.getmodule(meth),
                       meth.__qualname__.split('.<locals>', 1)[0].rsplit('.', 1)[0],
                       None)
    return None  


def override(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        cls = get_class_that_defined_method(func)
        if hasattr(cls.__base__, func.__name__):
            getattr(cls.__base__, func.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

This can be used as follows.

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        print("call A.method")


class B(A):
    @override
    def method(self):
        print("call B.method")


B().method()
# call A.method
# call B.method
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `decorator` and `metaclass`

```
import inspect


def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        has_super = False
        for line in inspect.getsource(func).split('\n'):
            if line.strip().startswith("super"):
                has_super = True
                break
        if not has_super:
            super_method = getattr(super(self.__class__, self), func.__name__, None)
            if super_method:  
                super_method(*args, **kwargs)
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class MyMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, local):
        for attr in local:
            if callable(local[attr]):
                local[attr] = my_decorator(local[attr])
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, local)


class BaseClass:
    
    def __init__(self):
        print("BaseClass __init__")

    def method1(self):
        print("BaseClass method1")

    def method2(self):
        print("BaseClass method2")


class Child(BaseClass, metaclass=MyMeta):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Child __init___")

    def method1(self):
        print("Child method1")

    def method2(self):
        print("Child method2")
        super().method2()


if __name__=="__main__":
    a = Child()
    a.method1()
    a.method2()
```

**Output**

```
BaseClass __init__
Child __init___
BaseClass method1
Child method1
Child method2
BaseClass method2
```

Answer (score -2):

While you can not force the call to the superclass, what you can do is force the call of one function when ANOTHER one is overridden:

```py
class Parent:
    def other_method(self):
        # code that would be in overridden function should be placed here
        print("Hello from parent!")

    def method(self):
        pass

    def run_method(self):
        self.other_method()
        self.method()


class Child(Parent):
    def method(self):
        print("Hello from child!")


myChild= Child()
# calling method() here will not have the desired effect, one needs to call run_method()
myChild.run_method()
```

This will produce following output:

```
Hello from parent!
Hello from child!
```

The child method is overriding `method()` without calling `super()`.